# Adding Columns from different dataframes (with matching date) stored in a python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have columns with the same name in several dataframes. these dataframes are stored in a dictionary. now i want to add the columns with the same name (and the respective date) across those dataframes in the dictionary and store the result in a new dataframe.

The code I have so far doest get me very far...

```
#create a new empty dataframe   
sum_df  = pd.DataFrame()
# my dataframes are stored in the dictionary frames_dict
for tables in frames_dict:
    df = frames_dict[tables]
    df = df[(df['date'] >= '01.01.2010') & (df['date'] <'01.01.2011')] 
    #here I filter for all columns starting with "a4_"
    filter_col = [col for col in list(df) if col.startswith('a4_')]
    df2 = df[["date","filter_col"]
    sum_df = sum_df + df2
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Initialize 'sum_df'
sum_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date'])

# Iterate over dataframes of dictionary
for i, tables in enumerate(frames_dict):

    # Create dataframe
    df = frames_dict[tables]

    # Filter rows by 'date'
    df = df[(df['date'] >= '01.01.2010') & (df['date'] <'01.01.2011')] 

    # Filter for all columns starting with "a4_"
    filter_col = [col for col in list(df) if col.startswith('a4_')]

    # Keep only proper cols
    df2 = df[['date'] + filter_col]

    # Join new columns from dictionary to old 'sum_df' dataframe
    if i == 0:
        sum_df = df2.rename(columns={i:'{}_{}'.format(i, tables) for i in filter_col}).copy()
    else:
        df2 = df2.rename(columns={i:'{}_{}'.format(i, tables) for i in filter_col})
        sum_df = df2.merge(sum_df, how='outer', on=['date']) #, suffixes=('_{}'.format(tables), '_y'))
        # Use either 'suffix' for renaming or 'df2 = df2.rename()' or both...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried to implement your code, however I receive the following error at line: "df = pd.DataFrame({tables:frames_dict[tables]})"  --> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index. Which index should I use?

Comment: Would you please pass a sample from your `frames_dict`?

Comment: datum a1_1000 a4_1045 a5_1464
0 2009-01-01 340.780 nan nan
1 2009-01-02 493.660 nan nan
2 2009-01-03 3754.860 nan nan
3 2009-01-04 7580.570 nan nan
4 2009-01-05 9582.770 nan nan
5 2009-01-06 7525.220 5370.350 nan

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your problem, so you have a dictionary of dataframes... I updated my code

Comment: Great, thank you very much! now the code works! However, it returns now a dataframe with all columns appended, however it has no rows i.e. "0 rows x 2806 columns"

Comment: Sorry, in the last row of code I used `df` instead of `df2`... (corrected)

Comment: still no luck :S i tried to fill the sum_df['date'] column with dates from another dataframe as it appears to me that the merge does not work if the dates column is empty, however it still does not seem to work. Or am i wrong on this one?

Comment: Yes, empty `date` column caused the problem (without sample data it's not so easy to solve a problem :). I updated again the code

Comment: WOW you are awesome!! Thank you so much! Is there also a way to see the dataframe name in the columns? now i see a4_1045_x,  a4_1045_y repeated 29 times. Would be great if I could replace x and y with the name of the dataframe so i can see from which dataframe the column originates

Comment: I updated again :) You can use `suffixes` in `merge` for special column names but I prefer `df.rename()` to get unique column names. If you want "dataframe name" + "column name" then change `.format(tables, i)` at both (`if` & `else`) `rename`.

Comment: Sir you deserve more medals! Works like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. You also can vote for this answer to have more reputation. Thx!